# prevent freeze gif file at the same time searching text in database

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want search data in database and show result. When I searching word in db, I want show a group box(**GbLoading**) with label and gif image control, But gif file freeze when searching word. How can I change my code for prevent freezing gif image in group box of form.

my code is :

```
private  void  BtSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GbLoading.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - 100, this.Height / 2 - 30);
    GbLoading.Visible = true;
    Application.DoEvents();

    List<BookAuthorsFieldSet> Resources = Db.Search(ResourceOrAutor, TxSearch.Text.Trim());
    DataTable Dt = ConvertListToDataTable(Resources);
    DgvResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource = Dt;
    DgvResourcesOrAuthorsCount.Text = "Result Count : " + DgvResourcesOrAuthors.Rows.Count.ToString();
    Application.DoEvents();
    DgvSpecialResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource = null;                    

    GbLoading.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Good time to read about async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Do an asynctask for the db search/load. I'd also suggest your activity Implements an interface that you create, perhaps ILoadCompleted with one method loadcompleted or something like that. Then you send a reference to your activity and on postexecute you use your reference ILoadCompleted to execute the loadcompleted so your activity knows that the asynctask is done.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB class support async methods then use them. If not, then you can create a Task and await it

```
List<BookAuthorsFieldSet> Resources = await Task.Run(
                () => Db.Search(ResourceOrAutor, TxSearch.Text.Trim()));
```

PS: Don't forget to mark your method as `async`

For .Net 4.0

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => Db.Search(ResourceOrAutor, TxSearch.Text.Trim()) )
.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    //Move the rest of your code here....
    List<BookAuthorsFieldSet> Resources = t.Result;
    //......

},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Please change my code, my framework is 4.